# How tocreate a sub task in JIRA using REST api

Tags: rest, jira

How to create a Sub task using REST API.
I Could not find any document.

Or is there any method to create a issue and link it with some parent issue.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as we create simple issue, we need to add "parent":{"id":"10101"} in our json string